# How to call a variable from another function defined under same class using dag?

Tags: python, class, python-3.7, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a function in my defined class and I am using @dag to call each function once. function1() is already returning an output to a variable and I want to use the same variable in function2(). How shall I use it to optimize my program?

I have already tried calling the function but it does not find the variable.

```
class A (enrich):
    @classmethod
    def GetQuote(cls, key = None, d={}):
        quote = [d.get(k) for k in key]
        if quote == 'Y':
            return 'Y'
        else:
            return 'N'        

    @classmethod
    def GetPrice(cls, key = None, d={}):
        custPrice = d.get(key, '')
        if cls.GetQuote.quote == 'Y':
            return 'Y'
        else:
            return 'N'
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense; maybe you should explain what you are trying to do. If the parent class `enrich` is useful to understand, you should probably post it too.

Comment: Why `'Y'` and `'N'` instead of the boolean values `True` and `False`?

Comment: Its fetching the data from a DB where the raw data comes in as 'Y' and 'N'.

Comment: Class(enrich) is calling another class from where it decodes the incoming data dictionary. GetPrice() does use other parameters as well but if they're blank then it should use quote.